# jaxb unmarshalling - unexpected element exception

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I try to unmarshalling an XML File to an Object.

I got this error:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (URI:"", lokal:"ORDER"). Expected elements are <{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ACCOUNT>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ACCOUNTING_INFO>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ADDRESS>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}AGREEMENT>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ARTICLE_ID>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ARTICLE_PRICE>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}BUYER_AID>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}BUYER_PARTY>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}CARD>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}CASH>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}CATALOG_REFERENCE>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}CHECK>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}CONTACT>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}CONTROL_INFO>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}COST_CATEGORY_ID>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}DEBIT>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}DELIVERY_DATE>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}DELIVERY_PARTY>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}FINAL_DELIVERY_PARTY>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}INTERNATIONAL_AID>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}INTERNATIONAL_RESTRICTIONS>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}INVOICE_PARTY>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}MANUFACTURER_INFO>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}MIME>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}MIME_INFO>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ORDER>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ORDER_HEADER>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ORDER_INFO>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ORDER_ITEM>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ORDER_ITEM_LIST>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ORDER_PARTIES>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ORDER_SUMMARY>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}PARTY>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}PARTY_ID>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}PAYMENT>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}PAYMENT_TERM>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}PHONE>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}PRICE_FLAG>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}PUBLIC_KEY>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}REMARK>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}SHIPMENT_PARTIES>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}SOURCING_INFO>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}SPECIAL_TREATMENT_CLASS>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}SUPPLIER_PARTY>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}TRANSPORT>,<{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}TRANSPORT_PARTY>
```

My unmarshelling process looks like:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(xmlfile);
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( ORDER.class );
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
ORDER order = (ORDER) u.unmarshal(is);
```

My XML Entity looks like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "orderheader",
    "orderitemlist",
    "ordersummary"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ORDER")
public class ORDER {

    @XmlElement(name = "ORDER_HEADER", required = true)
    protected ORDERHEADER orderheader;
    @XmlElement(name = "ORDER_ITEM_LIST", required = true)
    protected ORDERITEMLIST orderitemlist;
    @XmlElement(name = "ORDER_SUMMARY", required = true)
    protected ORDERSUMMARY ordersummary;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "version")
    protected String version;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String type;

    getters and setters
}
```

My XMLFile looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ORDER version="1.0" type="standard">
    <ORDER_HEADER>
        ...
    </ORDER_HEADER>
    <ORDER_ITEM_LIST>
        <ORDER_ITEM>
            ...
        </ORDER_ITEM>
    </ORDER_ITEM_LIST>
    <ORDER_SUMMARY>
        ...
    </ORDER_SUMMARY>
</ORDER>
```

So what is wrong with my unmarshalling process?
The XML Entitys are created with xjc.

I tried it also with simple xml files/objects. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message basically boils down to:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
  Unexpected element: <{}ORDER>
  Expected element: <{http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0}ORDER>
```

Basically, the error is that your schema is for namespace `http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0`, but your document doesn't have a namespace.

To make it work, you have 3 choices:

1. Add namespace to XML data
2. Remove namespace from XML schema
3. Parse without namespace support

I'd suggest #1, if possible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ORDER version="1.0" type="standard" xmlns="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0">
    <ORDER_HEADER>
        ...
    </ORDER_HEADER>
    <ORDER_ITEM_LIST>
        <ORDER_ITEM>
            ...
        </ORDER_ITEM>
    </ORDER_ITEM_LIST>
    <ORDER_SUMMARY>
        ...
    </ORDER_SUMMARY>
</ORDER>
```